# How to change zabbix retry interval automatically?

Tags: zabbix

For example, the normal check interval for an item is 10 minutes. But if a check failure found, the next retries will change their interval to 1 minutes. In the next 3 minutes, if 3 failure detected, a problem is triggered.

It is very useful for us to get a problem report in time. If Zabbix still uses the normal interval, 30 minutes will pass before we got notification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in like that, but it could be [achieved with the Zabbix API](http://www.zabbixbook.com/2016/10/24/using-the-zabbixtiny-to-change-an-item-interval-based-on-a-trigger/).

Comment: Thank you very much~